# The 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ' in jsonp

Tags: node.js, jsonp

I have already get the response json data from server to browser, but it is confused that the data can not be displayed in the browser and I found the error in the console that told me 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'. Here is my code in node js.

```
function callFacebook(){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.37.179:8888/facebook/connect?callback_=[TIMESTAMP]",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp:"jsonp",
    cache: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
        execute(data);
    },
    error:function() { console.log('Uh Oh!'); }
});
```

}
and here is the response json data:
    `res.header('Content-Type','application/json');
    res.header('Charset','utf-8');
    res.send({"something": "father"});`

Comment: You can remove the `?callback_=[TIMESTAMP]` from your url, since you are specifying to jQuery to automatically use jsonp

Comment: Script implies you should send JSONP, not just JSON

Comment: @BradM the callback query parameter here does not indicate auto JSONP (because it does not have question mark on the right side). JSONP is explicitly specified via dataType

Comment: Why do you try to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead of JSON? That `http://192.168.37.179:8888` seems to be your own site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the server you are sending just normal JSON data, but on client you are expecting JSONP.
The response from server is not JSONP and browser does throw exception as syntax is wrong.

If you need to send JSONP from server, then if you are using express add extra `use`:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('jsonp callback', true);
});
```

Then to send JSONP just slightly change `res`. You don't need to set any header anymore, as they will be automatically detected:

```
res.jsonp({ hello: 'world' });
```

On client side, jQuery will add callback it self, so use just this simplified way:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://192.168.37.179:8888/facebook/connect",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  cache: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log('error[' + status + '] jsonp');
  }
});
```

As well if your node is proxied through nginx or any other web platform, don't forget to enable `utf8` encoding there.