# JSONP undefined in node.js, use .send will cause unexpected token error

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, express, jsonp

I'm using JSONP in my node.js function:

```
this.send(JSON.stringify({
    type: 'hello',
    username: this.data('username'),
    friends: friends
}));
```

However, it gives me an unexpected token ":" error(which i don't see in json). After reading this post: [The 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ' in jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406990/the-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-jsonp)

I found out it might be a json/jsonp issue. so I changed my code to:

```
this.jsonp(JSON.stringify({
    type: 'hello',
    username: this.data('username'),
    friends: friends
}));
```

However, it says this has no method "jsonp". I can't use send either because I was using jsonp in my client side. This is weird because I can use jsonp anywhere else but here. Here are some functions in the user.js file.

```
User.prototype.send = function(code, message, callback) {
    this._send('listener', code, message, callback);
};

User.prototype._send = function(type, code, message, callback) {
    if(!message && typeof code != 'number') {
        callback = message;
        message = code;
        code = 200;
    }

    if(typeof message != 'string')
        message = JSON.stringify(message);

    if(type == 'connection' && this.connection) {
        this.connection.writeHead(code || 200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': message.length
        });
        this.connection.end(message);
    } else {
        if(!this.listeners.length)
            return this.message_queue.push(arguments);

        var cx = this.listeners.slice(), conn;
        this.listeners = [];
        while(conn = cx.shift()) {
            conn.writeHead(code || 200, {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Content-Length': message.length
            });
            conn.end(message);
        }
        if(callback) callback();
    }
};
```

Looks like it's calling the send function inside, however, I can't find where to change this json to jsonp so it won't throw me unexpected token error in the client side.(Right now it did since the json and jsonp issue).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding what jsonp is. It's not a magical ajax that can bypass the same origin policy. It works in browsers like this:

1. Get the url of the jsonp data.
2. Create a function that will handle the jsonp data.
3. Append the function name as a parameter to the jsonp url.
4. Create a script tag in the DOM with a src attribute of that url.
5. The jsonp server sees that a request has come in and wraps the json data in a call to the function parameter.
6. The script loads on your page and executes the function.

Though jQuery and some other frameworks make this LOOK like an XMLHttpRequest, it is far from it.

Just because you had to use jsonp on the client side doesn't mean you have to do it in node. Have you looked at the API of the external server and made sure you have tried creating a correct GET, PUT, or POST request?

Comment: Thank you for your help :-) You are Right. However, if I use app.send() instead of app.jsonp(), it gives me an error about unexpected token ":". I read some posts and it seems like to be a jsonp vs json issue....What should I do?

Comment: Are you using Express?

Comment: Yes. I am using Express.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to take a deeper look and then comment again.

Comment: Thank you! It's not an server.js file. This is a middleware file.

Comment: One more question.  I may have misunderstood you initially.  Are you trying to SERVE a jsonp request?

Comment: Well i have an ajax call typed as jsonp from the client side(different domain) and calls this node.js server to get callback.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Are you getting the error on the client side or the server side?  Also, could you show what the message content you're trying to send actually looks like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38508/discussion-between-rescuecreative-and-jackhao)