# JSONP - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

before I explain my issue I would like to mention that I'm a naive on `jsonp`. This is actually my very first attempt to work with `JSONP`.

Im using jquery ajax call to pullback data from a website.

my jquery code is below

```
$.fn.checkTPS = function(){

    return this.each(function(){
        var interval;

        $(this).on('keyup', function() {
            var api_key = 'asdfasfsadfsadfsad';
            var format = 'json';
            var username = 'dame@example.co.uk';

            var self = $(this);
            var selfValue;
            var feedback = $('.tps-feedback');

            if(interval === undefined){

                interval = setInterval(function(){

                    if(selfValue !== self.val()) {

                        selfValue = self.val();

                        if (selfValue.length > 9){
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'https://www.selectabase.co.uk/api/v1/tps/' + selfValue + '/',
                                type: 'get',
                                dataType: 'jsonp',
                                data: {
                                    format: format,
                                    username: username,
                                    api_key: api_key
                                },
                                success: function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                },
                                error: function() {

                                },
                                jsonp: 'jsonp'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },3000);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I want to accommodate a service from `selectabase.co.uk`, according to them this is how I should use the service `https://www.selectabase.co.uk/api/v1/tps/[number]/?format=json&username=[username]&api_key=[api key]`

when I send request using ajax I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` and when clicked this opens up 
`{"ctps": false, "number": "1452500705", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/tps/01452500705/", "tps": false}` by the way this I want but don't know what's this error is **`unexpected token :`**

I've copied the following link from inspect element tab (you can see the image below) I think this is the call that has been generated by json `https://www.selectabase.co.uk/api/v1/tps/01452500705/?jsonp=jQuery17102731868715648129_14120077325500&format=json&username=dame40example.co.uk&api_key=asdfasfsadfsadfsad&_=14120077325500`

I copied the link below from `inspect element > source tab` in chrome.. I think I should add an image to describe properly where this json data and link I've copied from.

[image]

I hope I've manage to convey my message across... please help if you have any Idea what do i need to add... Regards

Comment: The server is sending back JSON, not JSONP. That's the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406990/the-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-jsonp , http://stackoverflow.com/a/19166256/2864740

Comment: but then if i use `dataType: 'json'` browser dosent send the request to that url

Comment: @Sharif The server needs to respond with JSONP itself.

Answer (score 6):

The `format=json` in your query string should probably be `format=jsonp`. The server is replying with JSON, but you're expecting a JSONP response. But I don't know that they support `format=jsonp`, it's just a guess.

Alternately, *if* that server supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and allows requests from your origin, you could handle JSON instead (just remove `dataType: "json"` from your `ajax` call). Beware that that would require that the user be using a browser that [properly supports CORS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors), which IE8 and IE9 don't. (They support CORS, but not via the normal `XMLHttpRequest` object, and this is a browser inconsistency that jQuery *doesn't* smooth over for you. If you search, though, you can find "plugins" or similar that will handle it.)

Comment: this format is nothing to do with ajax jsonp this is how they want to send data `?format=json&username=[username]&api_key=[api key]`

Comment: @Sharif: Normally, if a service like that has a `format` query string param, they support multiple formats (JSON, XML, and JSONP are all popular). This one may or may not, but again, since they appear to support CORS, you could use JSON if that's all they offer.

Comment: @Sharif: *"I've tried with jsonp too but still the same error"* Yeah, I'm not sure they do actually support JSONP, just JSON. (That would be odd, but I kicked around with their page a bit and that's what it looks like...) So you'd have to go with the second paragraph of the answer.

Comment: I've just removed dataType: 'jsonp from code and this error XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.selectabase.co.uk/api/v1/tps/01452523652/?format=json&username=oliver%40asdfsdf.co.uk&api_key=asdfsafsadf. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://claims-pro.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Sharif: Darn, that means they don't support CORS from your origin. If they don't support JSONP and don't support CORS from your origin, you can't query this information client-side. You'll need to query your own server, and have your server query them.

Comment: Crowder but how I'm getting that json array back if i use dataType:'json'.. eventhough javascript not reading this an object but the data is right

Comment: @Sharif: What's going on is this: When you say `dataType: 'jsonp'`, you're telling jQuery to use a `script` element to load the data, setting the `script`'s `src` to your URL. And that works and retrieves the data (as a script), because you can load scripts cross-domain. But you can't use it, because it's JSON, not script; that's why you see the syntax error. JSONP is a means of using `script` elements to deliver data cross-origin without CORS, but it only works if both sides are playing along. It would appear the server here *isn't*, so you cannot get this data client-side directly.

Comment: thank you very much for clear and concise answer @T.J. Crowder... let me speak to the company.. regards

Comment: now i'm getting this error with the same code `send jquery.min.js:4f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function)` :(